# Redirect Page no response AJAX em Asp.net Mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou tendo problemas para redirecionar uma página, no response do meu Ajax, quando estou no FireFox em modo debug, consigo redirecionar, sem Debug a página so da um refresh, tentei outros redirects também falharam, só funciona com Debug aberto, ao carregar a página a requisição joga pra um filtro que valida o usuário no método OnActionExecuting, como eu disse, no Debug do navegador tudo funciona. Alguém tem alguma idéia ?

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/MyApplication/Account/Login",
            data: dataObject,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            datatype:"json",
            success: function (response) {

                if (response.result == 'redirect') {

                    window.location.href = "/MyApplication/Home/List";

                }
            },
```

Comment: faz um `console.log(response)` acredito que daí consigo te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Agora consegui colocar pra funcionar mas somente no Chrome, no Fire Fox a chamada AJAX vai até a Action e depois não retorna nem success nem error.
A resposta do response é essa:
Object {result: "redirect", url: "/MyApplication/Home/List"}

Comment: Estou usando  window.location.assign(response.url); com async: true, do ajax, funcionando apenas Chrome